# MFC CFileDialog prevent from opening *.ext.other_ext files

Tags: mfc, modal-dialog

I'm trying to create file dialog using the next code:

```
CFileDialog fd (TRUE, NULL, _T("*.pid"), OFN_FILEMUSTEXIST | OFN_HIDEREADONLY);

fd.m_ofn.lpstrInitialDir=m_CurrentDir;

if (fd.DoModal() == IDOK)
...
```

When the dialog is opened I see both **.pid* and **.pid.saved* files.
Is there any to prevent from the dialog to show me **.pid.saved* files?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must specify the filter the dialog should use:

```
LPCTSTR szFilter = _T( "PID Files (*.pid)|*.pid|All Files (*.*)|*.*" );
DWORD dwFlags =  OFN_FILEMUSTEXIST | OFN_HIDEREADONLY;
CFileDialog dlg( TRUE, _T( "pid" ), NULL, dwFlags, szFilter );  
dlg.DoModal();
...
```

Comment: Thanks Eddie, you made my day as well. This is so simple but I struggled with it for some time.